# What is the best option for passing data from SSIS to WCF?

Tags: wcf, ssis

We are trying to get data out of a SQL Server DB and submit it to a WCF web service. Since using a windows service is not a option in this case, I thought of using SSIS.

I have tried using the Web Service Task, but I'm having difficulties getting it to work. I also understand there are limitation to using Web Service Task. What is the best option for use to pass data from SSIS to WCF? Note: We are restricted in using CLR Integration in SQL.

Comment: Will you be giving the WCF service access to the datasource where SSIS result will be stored??

Answer (score 0):

worth checking out [Accessing Web Services in SQL Server 2005](http://sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/53966/sql_server_53966.html)

I am not sure if it is the best option but you could use OLE automation within stored proc to invoke the web service.

[Call GeoNames Web Services from a SQL Stored Procedure](http://blog.davebouwman.net/2008/07/09/CallGeoNamesWebServicesFromASQLStoredProcedure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is not use WCF and use traditional webservice.  If the WCF service is not under your control.  You could use a traditional webservice to call the wcf service.